# Determine whether or not $H = \{x \in \mathbb R: \tan(x) \in \mathbb Q\}$ is a subgroup of $G = (\mathbb R, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need someone who can verify my argument below works.

$G = (\mathbb R, +)$

$H = \{x \in \mathbb R: \tan(x) \in \mathbb Q\}$

I reached a conclusion that $H$ is not a subgroup, reasoning:

(1) Identity (zero) exists in $H$ since $\tan(0)$ is a rational.

(2) (Part I need verification on): $H$ is not closed with respect to addition.

**Argument:**
Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb R: \tan(x), \tan(y) \in \mathbb Q$, then $x,y \in H$.

Then, we need to check is $x+y$ is in $H$.

**Assume** $x+y$ is in $H$.

Then that implies $\tan(x+y) \in \mathbb Q$.

**But,**

$$\tan(x+y)=\dfrac{\tan(x) + \tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}.$$

I know for a fact that the numerator is a rational since both parts of the numerator are rationals. **The issue is the denominator:**

We cannot have $1-\tan(x)\tan(y) = 0$.

But if $x = 1.10714872, y = 0.463647609$, $\tan(x+y)$ will be undefined.

Thus $H$ is not closed since there exist $x,y$ input that gives an output not in the reals.

Is my logic here correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. It is true that if $\tan(x)$, $\tan(x)$, and $\tan(x+y)$ are all defined, then $\tan(x), \tan(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$ implies $\tan(x+y) \in \mathbb{Q}$, by the addition formula. But the problem happens if $\tan(x+y)$ is undefined.

To give a counterexample, you may pick choose specific $x$ and $y$ that do it, and I would give exact values, not decimal approximations.

So one might say: "Let $x = \tan^{-1}(2)$ and $y \in \tan^{-1}(1/2)$." Argue that $x$ and $y$ are in $H$, but $\tan(x+y)$ is undefined. Then you can conclude that $x + y \notin H$.

It may be easier to use $x = y = \pi/4$; then you can see explicitly that $\tan(x) = \tan(y) = 1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, but $\tan (x+y) = \tan(\pi/2)$ is undefined.

---

Note that if $H$ is instead defined as $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \tan(x) \in \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}\}$, then $H$ is indeed a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks! One side note: what do we mean by $\mathbb{Q} \cup {\infty}$?

Comment: I just mean the set of rationals together with something named $\infty$, where, say, $\tan(\pi/2) = \infty$ (instead of leaving it undefined).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @arkeet - this should be $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \tan(x) \in \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\} \cup \{-\infty\}\}$, otherwise $H$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: @NickyHekster What's the difference between $\infty$ and $-\infty$? (Look at how $\tan$ behaves on each side of a singularity.) I'm thinking of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ as the projective real line, with no distinction between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.